# How to change price of a product using preference

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.5, mageplaza

Hey im new to magento and i want to change the price of a product using preference can any one help me with the sample code

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the etc/di.xml file in your extension folder:
   **app/code/MyCompany/ModuleName/etc/frontend/di.xml** and add the below code

   ```
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" type="MyCompany\ModuleName\Plugin\Product"/>
    </config>
   ```
2. create **Product.php** file in your extension folder:
   **app/code/MyCompany/ModuleName/Plugin/Product.php** and add below code

   ```
    <?php
   namespace MyCompany\ModuleName\Plugin;
   class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
   {
     public function getPrice()
     {
       $extraprice = 5;// you can set price
       if ($this->_calculatePrice || !$this->getData(self::PRICE)) {
           return $this->getPriceModel()->getPrice($this) + $extraprice; // you can add price
         } else {
           return $this->getData(self::PRICE);
         }
      }
   }
   ```
3. Run the **php bin/magento setup:di:compile** command and check.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, here is an example of how you can change the price of a product using preferences in Magento 2:

1. Create a new module, let's call it "PriceChanger".
2. In the `etc` directory of your module, create a `di.xml` file and add the following code:

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product" type="PriceChanger\Model\Product"/>
</config>
```

3. Create a new file in the Model directory of your module, called `Product.php` and add the following code:

```
<?php

namespace PriceChanger\Model;

class Product extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product
{
    public function setPrice($price)
    {
        $newPrice = $price + 10;
        return parent::setPrice($newPrice);
    }
}
```

4. In this example, the price of the product will be increased by 10 every time it is set.
5. You can now use the setPrice method to increase the price of the product by 10.

**Note:** This is just a sample code, you can use the same logic to decrease or change the price as per your requirement.